# Why do I keep getting Error 400 after post in Android?

Tags: android, http-post, spotify, httpconnection

I'm building an app that logs with user credentials to Spotify. I follow this API call: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow

And this is the implenentation code:

```
@Override
protected Session doInBackground(String... params) {

    Session session = new Session();



    try {
        String response = "";
        URL url = new URL(GET_TOKEN_URL);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        String credentials = params[0]+":"+params[1];
        String basicAuth ="Basic "+new String(android.util.Base64.encode(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter(GRANT_TYPE, CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(AUTH, basicAuth);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(POST);


        httpURLConnection.connect();

        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        int responseCode=httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

        session.setResponseCode(responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "RESPONSE:" + responseCode);
           // response = "Something went wrong";
        }
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), response);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{

    }
    return session;
}
```

But no matter what I change, I'm always getting an Error 400.

What am I doing wrong?

Update:

I performed a curl with an online tool following the exact syntax of the Spotify Developer webpage and I still have an HTTP STATUS 400 [image]

Comment: For starters, listen to what the server is telling you.  400 is the HTTP response code for "Bad Request".  It means the server is not satisfied with the request you have sent it.  It may be lacking information or contain incorrectly-formatted information.

Comment: looks like you might have a typo in your code.  I see a semi-colon after "else"

Comment: @EJK Yes, I'm forming the POST with the Parameters that Spotify needs to perform the loging. Im asuming Im building something wrong.

Comment: Also, i checked the typo. Fixed but the problem persists

Comment: 2 other problems I see: (1) Your Content-Length header.  You are computing this as the size of the query string.  That is wrong as it is supposed to be the size of the body.  Just omit this and the header should be generated for you.  (2) You are putting the grant type in the query string.  According to the documentation link you posted, it does not belong there.  It looks like it belongs in the body.

Comment: I have consolidated these comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting the following errors

1) Fix the typo in your `else`.  There should be no semi-colon after the else.

2) Remove your code that calculates the content length and adds the header.  The length should be that of the body, not the query string as you have coded.  If you simply remove this code, the HttpUrlConnection class should generate this header for you.

3) Put the grant type parameter in the body.  That is where the documentation says it belongs.  You have it in the query string.  You should be able to use the following code:

```
String body =  GRANT_TYPE + "=" + CLIENT_CREDENTIALS;
byte[] bodyBytes = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
stream.write(bodyBytes);    
stream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try and post results in a second

Comment: Done. But the response is still a 400 Error. Im looking the Spotify API. Maybe i adding the body wrong

Comment: The debbuger says that the httpconnection has a "GET" method. Could that be tracked down to the source of the problem.

Comment: Hmmm.   You already have: httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(POST);

Comment: Just for kicks, can you try setting it to httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  // note the quotes

Comment: Good news, I removed a few Ifs, and Im getting a FileNotFoundException for https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. Does not ring a bell for me tho.

Comment: Well. Im going to start over. No solution works so far but ill accept yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121384/discussion-between-chntgomez-and-ejk).